# Can't cascade delete or update in Nhibernate if several Entities has references to the same source

Tags: nhibernate, cascade, fluent, cascading-deletes

I have such mapping of ChargeOperations(left table) and Distributions(right table):

[image: Mapping image]
In code mapping of ChargeOperations looks like:

```
 HasMany(x => x.Distributions).Table("ShadowDistributions").KeyColumn("SourceId").Cascade.All().Inverse();
```

ShadowDistributions - is a right table. x.Distributions is a just a list of Distributions(right table). X - is ChargeOperation(left table)

Mapping of Distributions (right table)

```
References(x => x.Source).Nullable().Column("SourceId").Not.LazyLoad();
References(x => x.Dest).Nullable().Column("Dest").LazyLoad().Fetch.Join().Cascade.All();
```

So, I want to delete just one row from Distributions (right table).
And the applications throws different mapping exceptions like "Transaction could not commit because of a failed resource : deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[ChargeOperation#58]"" or "Unexpected row count: 0; expected: 1" and so on.

---

I use cascade for creating entities and it works great, but for delete I had to
clean all references in the right table, and after that save all types of entities separately. If not, I'll get errors.

But I'd like to use cascade saving. How can I realize it?

Possible variants after save:

1. deleted just one record from right table. all records in left
   table are exist
2. deleted just two records from right table. all
   records in left table are also deleted

Comment: If I try to delete a Distribution in cascade mode Nhibernate try to delete all entities but all I need - just delete the entities itself without cascad. But If create entities, I need a cascade!

Answer (score 1):

Change your Cascade to `Cascade.SaveUpdate()` if you don't wish to delete any of the referenced entities.

In my opinion you shouldn't be trying to delete a parent (`ChargeOperations`) whenever you delete one of the children (`Distributions`)

#### Example

```
public SomeMethod()
{    
    using(ISession session = ... //Get my session from somewhere)
    {
        Distribution childToDelete = ... //Get the distribution to delete
        ChargeOperation parent = ... //Get the parent of the distribution we are deleting

        parent.Distributions.Remove(childToDelete);

        //Since the parent is in session just flush the session to apply changes
        session.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't helped. IT was my first solution.
{"deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)[ChargeOperation#58]"}
the only thing which helps - set nulls to Source and Dest in left table before it's saved...

Comment: I don't try to delete parant(ChargeOperation). Only children(Distributions). But If parent has no children, I delete it too. But in current situation, All parents are alive, because they have other children

Comment: You need to remove the `Distribution` from the collection in `ChargeOperations`.  Check if the `ChargeOperations` have any `Distributions` left after the removal and if the count is 0 delete the `ChargeOperations`

Comment: I do all you said. Delete Distribution from collection, delete distribution from repository, update chargeOperation repository.  And recieve that error message. Don't understand why.

Comment: @Artem I have posted an example of what I'm talking about.  It sounds like you are doing a lot of unnecessary things to delete that child.  If the above does not work for you then you need to post how you are currently retrieving/updating these entities.